# How do I change RRDTool graphs?

Tags: charts, highcharts, rrdtool, rrd, ganglia

I'm starting to use Ganglia, which uses `rrdtool` which are great tools!
I would like to change the way of charts, graphs are generated, 'cause I would like to generate charts with [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). RRDTool generates an `img` which I can change the way it's generated.

Is that is possible ? How could I do that ?
Thank you.

Comment: are you looking to leverage the data from the RRD to build a different chart via highcharts?

Comment: @austin, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://thule.mine.nu/html/about.html) page.  It gives a pretty good description, and some example code.

Good Luck!

Comment: The link is no longer valid since dyndns stopped their free tier. I have moved the tutorial to my personal blog at: http://blog.tafkas.net/2012/10/03/gathering-and-charting-temperatures-using-rrdtool-and-highcharts/